# jQuery animate issues, hover becoming default state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small system where in a page is populated with images, hovering over the image animates a background color over the image and scrolls some text over the image. Then when you stop hovering the text scrolls off and background fades out with the following code:

```
$j('.projects .block .mob_hide').hover(function(){
                                console.log('sliding detals');
                                $j(this).find('.background').stop().animate({
                                    'opacity': 'toggle'
                                }, 400);
                                $j(this).find('.text').stop().animate({
                                    'height': 'toggle',
                                    'opacity': 'toggle'
                                }, 400);
                            });
```

Now this all works fine, however sometimes if a user scrolls over the image when the page is perhaps still loading (I'm not 100% sure) the mouse hover state is displayed without the mouse being over the image (and now hovering over hides and unhovering displays).

Is there a way to counter this problem? m code is currently inside a window.load function and i assumed that would stop such things from being possible.

Comment: try creating a jsfiddle so we can reproduce your problem and work on a solution..

Comment: Did you put your jQuery call inside a $(document).ready(function () { /* HERE */ }); ?
It would be better to see how do you call your script, in order to try to help you !

Comment: They said "m code is currently inside a window.load function"

Comment: I read that, however it still would be better to see. JSFiddle should be a good way !

Comment: Maybe this happens because if the mouse is over `.mob_hide` when the event handlers are added (during page load), the first event will be a `mouseleave` and not `mouseenter`, and because the `animate` calls use `toggle`, everything is out of phase from that point forward. To counter this, you could split up your hover handler into hover-in and hover-out handlers, which each explicitly animate to the respectively desired state.